# Multiple PowerShell scripts to monitor a folder

Tags: powershell

I'm opening this one as it's related to another thread I've opened but not the same problem.

I currently have 2 scripts to monitor a folder. In this folder (a sharepoint site folder), is a powerpoint presentation running on a remote laptop. The goal is to have the possibility to change the presentation without having to go to the laptop itself (as there will eventually be a large number of them in remote locations).

So what I'm doing so far is a scrip1 that monitors when a file is dropped in the folder. This script then shut downs the presentation currently running.

Another script monitors if a ppt file is renamed in the folder (as the instructions will be: 1-dump your file 2-delete Slide.pptx 3- rename your new file as Slide.pptx). I then kicks off Powerpoint with the presentation file.

But don't know how to have both scripts running at the same time. Even having 1 calling 2 and when 2 has run it calls 1 again.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using [Dot Source](http://ss64.com/ps/source.html), or simply include some recursion/wait loops that call the additional scripts.  If this is supposed to go on forever (until manually cancelled), that is.

Comment: If there will be many files in the folder, how does it know what presentation to stop? Say you have Pres1.pptx, Pres2.pptx, and Pres3.pptx, and somebody wants to replace Pres2.pptx. They upload JohnSmith.pptx, how does the script know which presentation to stop to allow the file to be deleted so that the new pptx file can be correctly named?

Comment: There will be only one file in the folder. There can be more than one but the one to run will always have the same name, let's say Pres.ppsx. So you drop another file in the folder (that stops PPT), delete Pres.ppsx and rename the new one as Pres.ppsx. If I monitor the proper events, that should work :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't reinvent. You can use [PowershellGuard](https://github.com/smurawski/PowerShellGuard). Original ruby [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) is also what I have used for this purpose (it is way more mature).

Guards allow you to run multiple scripts mapped to file specification.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13047434)

Comment: The question doesn't have enough details for that.

Comment: Sorry, I've got no clue how to use PowerGuard. PowerShell noob here.